# How to drop all the tables in Codeigniter using Migration library

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, database-migration

I have created migrations files in Codeigniter 3 for the database using the `Migration` library provided by the CI and with the help of the online tutorials. My migrations file look like this,

```
<?php

class Migration_Leave_tracker extends CI_Migration {

    public function up() {
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'emp_id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
            ),
            'start_date' => array(
                'type' => 'DATE',
            ),
            'end_date' => array(
                'type' => 'DATE',
            ),
            'created_date' => array(
                'type' => 'DATETIME',
            ),
        ));
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('leave_tracker');
    }

    public function down() {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('leave_tracker');
    }

}
```

Here you can see that my migration file has two methods one is `up()` which is used to create the table and other is `down()` which can be used to drop the table.

I have another controller with a method to run the migrations,

```
public function migrate($version = null) {
        $this->load->library('migration');

        if ($version != null) {
            if ($this->migration->version($version) === FALSE) {
                show_error($this->migration->error_string());
            } else {
                echo "Migrations run successfully" . PHP_EOL;
            }

            return;
        }

        if ($this->migration->latest() === FALSE) {
            show_error($this->migration->error_string());
        } else {
            echo "Migrations run successfully" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

As per the CI documentation, this piece of the code will create all the migrations and I guess under the hood it will call the `up()` method of all the migrations class to create tables.

Now my question is how can I create a method which will drop all the tables in the database using the `drop()` method of migration class. I could not find any reference for that in the docs.

Comment: Typically a migration file will only drop tables (in `down()`) that were created in the class's `up()`.

Comment: @ DFriend that is all I want but the question is how to do that.

Comment: I was confused by your statement, "...will drop **all the tables** in the database".  (Emphasis mine) I figured out a way to do this, but it was a while back. I'll look for the code when time allows and share it here. Might be a day or two,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following migration controller with good results.

```
class Migrator extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->load->library('migration');
    }

    public function migrate($version = NULL)
    {

        $outcome = $this->migration->version($version);

        if(is_string($outcome))
        {
            echo "Migration to version $outcome succeeded.";
        }
        elseif($outcome === TRUE)
        {
            echo "No migration was possible. Target version is the same as current version.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $this->migration->error_string();
        }
    }

    public function latest() //you could this for migration::current() too
    {
        $this->migration->latest();
    }

}
```

Assuming the use of "sequential" number on the migrations and `class Migration_Leave_tracker` is in file `001_Migration_Leave_tracker.php`

Then browsing to `http://example.com/migrator/migrate/1` will run `Migration_Leave_tracker::up()`.

To revert from that simply call `migrate` with a lower sequential number eg.
`http://example.com/migrator/migrate/0` which will result in Migration_Leave_tracker::down()` being called. (At least it does for me.)

Timestamp numbering works also but for the "final down" use zero as the argument to the URL. In other words, just use `http://example.com/migrator/migrate/0` like was done for sequential numbering.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked. I did not know that if provide 0 as migration version then it would drop the table.

Comment: It is not documented but probably should be.